# Grammar of the phrase 'her great ruddy face dripping.'

Tags: grammar

I'm confused with grammar of the next sentence. It is from "harry potter and the prisoner of azkaban".

"Shards of glass flew in every direction and Aunt Marge sputtered and blinked, her great ruddy face dripping."

The sense of the sentence is clear but could you please explain me the last part 'her great ruddy face dripping.'? It sounds for me like it's missing something else here and I can not find any grammar rule for this case.

Comment: The phrase you're asking about is called a **nominative absolute**. Here is a link to the description of this construction, with examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute (also, a definition here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominative%20absolute)  This construction is frequently asked about on ELL, but many answers don't refer to it by its "technical" name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Aunt Marge's (great ruddy) face {is}* ***dripping*** means that her face is *wet*, and the liquid is dripping off of it.  In context, her drinking glass just exploded, sending shards of glass everywhere, and so it's implied that the liquid inside that glass also went everywhere.  Everywhere includes her face, which is now dripping.

The verb "is" is implied, and optional.  Compare, "Sarah laughing" with "Sarah is laughing".

Possibly irrelevant to you question: "ruddy" means "red", which can mean "healthy" with regards to a face, or in British English can also be a [minced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) version of "bloody", as an intensifier.

Comment: And "ruddy" means "red". Usually it's a healthy kind of red. So "her big red face".

Comment: I didn't think that was the part the questioner had issue with, so I didn't mention it, but I'll add it in now.  Don't forget that ruddy can also be a polite "bloody" swear intensifier.

Comment: I did the easy bit. Haven't heard it used as a milder 'bloody' for years. Except in "The IT Crowd", where it was used humorously.

Comment: A ruddy face is usually a healthy or angry one, a ruddy door is a {expletive} door that's probably stuck... but its use here for Aunt Marge probably means *both* in a wink-wink-nod-nod sly sort of way, given how much Harry hates the woman.

Comment: You have written "Aunt Marge's (ruddy) face is dripping" but the phrase in the original text is 'her great ruddy face dripping.' So there is no 'is' or 'was'. My question was is it ok to use 'face dripping' without 'to be' part ?

Comment: *Is* is optional here.  It's an implied verb.  I'll add it to my answer for you.

Comment: I got it thank you

Comment: [While she] sputtered and blinked, her face [was] dripping.

Comment: No, the *is* is *not* optional, it's *wrong*. "Her great ruddy face dripping" is a clause, a sentence fragment. You can't add a verb in there, because it would make that last part a run-on sentence which is always a mistake.